# How to check if a service is running via batch file and stop it if it is not running?

Tags: if-statement, service, batch-file

I want a batch file to check if the service "MyServiceName" is running. If the service is running, I want the batch file to disable it and then display a message. If it isn't running, and is disabled, I want the batch file to display a message and then to exit. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

```
sc query MyServiceName| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && echo service is runnung
sc query MyServiceName| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 || echo service is not runnung
```

To stop service:

```
net stop MyServiceName
```

Answer (score 2):

If tried to come up with a little script that makes use of the `SC`-command, which seems to have some limitations though (and I couldn't test it):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Change this to your service name
set service=MyServiceName
:: Get state of service ("RUNNING"?)
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%a in ('sc query %service%') do (
  if "%%a"=="STATE" set state=%%b
)
:: Get start type of service ("AUTO_START" or "DEMAND_START")
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%a in ('sc qc %service%') do (
  if "%%a"=="START_TYPE" set start=%%b
)
:: If running: stop, disable and print message
if "%state%"=="RUNNING" (
  sc stop %service%
  sc config %service% start= disabled
  echo Service "%service%" was stopped and disabled.
  exit /b
)
:: If not running and start-type is manual, print message
if "%start%"=="DEMAND_START" (
  echo Start type of service %service% is manual.
  exit /b
)
:: If start=="" assume Service was not found, ergo is disabled(?)
if "%state%"=="" (
  echo Service "%service%" could not be found, it might be disabled.
  exit /b
)
```

I don't know if this gives the behavior you wanted. It seems like `SC` does not list services, that are disabled. But since you don't want to do anything if it's disabled, my code simply prints a message if the service wasn't found.

However, you can hopefully use my code as a framework/toolbox for your purposes.

**EDIT:**

Given npocmaka's answer, you could probably change the `for`-sections to something like:

```
sc query %service%| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && set running=true
```

Comment: `sc query state= all` (that space after the equals sign is importart) will get all services.

Comment: Ok, I see, thx. However, when you look for a specific name `SC` will return `STATE=STOPPED` anyway, so you might probably test `"%state%"=="STOPPED"` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This script takes the service name as the first (and only) parameter, or you can hardcode it into the SVC_NAME assignment. The output of the sc commands is thrown away. I don't know if you actually want to see it or not.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET SVC_NAME=MyServiceName
IF NOT "%~1"=="" SET "SVC_NAME=%~1"

SET SVC_STARTUP=
FOR /F "skip=1" %%s IN ('wmic path Win32_Service where Name^="%SVC_NAME%" get StartMode') DO (
    IF "!SVC_STARTUP!"=="" SET "SVC_STARTUP=%%~s"
)

CALL :"%SVC_STARTUP%" "%SVC_NAME%"
CALL :StopService "%SVC_NAME%"
GOTO :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:"Boot"
:"System"
:"Auto"
:"Manual"
@ECHO Disabling service '%~1'.
sc.exe config "%~1" start= disabled > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 @ECHO Service '%~1' disabled.
EXIT /B

:"Disabled"
@ECHO Service '%~1' already disabled.
EXIT /B


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:StopService
SETLOCAL
SET SVC_STATE=
FOR /F "skip=1" %%s IN ('wmic path Win32_Service where Name^="%~1" get State') DO (
   IF "!SVC_STATE!"=="" SET "SVC_STATE=%%~s"
)
CALL :"%SVC_STATE%" "%~1"
EXIT /B


:"Running"
:"Start Pending"
:"Continue Pending"
:"Pause Pending"
:"Paused"
:"Unknown"
@ECHO Stopping service '%~1'.
sc.exe stop "%~1" > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 @ECHO Service '%~1' stopped.

EXIT /B

:"Stop Pending"
:"Stopped"
@ECHO Service '%~1' is already stopping/stopped.
EXIT /B
```